# How to pass an arbitrary AppleScript Record to Cocoa in a scriptable app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, cocoa-scripting

I have a Cocoa application with an AppleScript dictionary described in a .sdef XML file. All of the AppleScript classes, commands, etc. defined in the sdef are working property.

Except for my "submit form" command. The "submit form" command is my only command attempting to pass a parameter that is an arbitrary hashtable of information from AppleScript to Cocoa. I assume this should be done by passing an AppleScript `record` which will be automatically converted to an `NSDictionary` on the Cocoa side.

```
tell application "Fluidium"
    tell selected tab of browser window 1
        submit form with name "foo" with values {bar:"baz"}
    end tell
end tell
```

The "with values" parameter is the `record` -> `NSDictionary` parameter i am having trouble with. Note that the keys of the record/dictionary cannot be known/defined in advance. They are arbitrary.

Here is the definition of this command in my sdef XML:

```
<command name="submit form" code="FuSSSbmt" description="...">
    <direct-parameter type="specifier" optional="yes" description="..."/>
    <parameter type="text" name="with name" code="Name" optional="yes" description="...">
        <cocoa key="name"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter type="record" name="with values" code="Vals" optional="yes" description="...">
        <cocoa key="values"/>
    </parameter>
</command>
```

And I have a "tab" object which responds to this command in the sdef:

```
<class name="tab" code="fTab" description="A browser tab.">
    ...
    <responds-to command="submit form">
        <cocoa method="handleSubmitFormCommand:"/>
    </responds-to>
```

and Cocoa:

```
- (id)handleSubmitFormCommand:(NSScriptCommand *)cmd {
    ...
}
```

The "tab" object correctly responds to all the other AppleScript commands I have defined. The "tab" object also responds to the "submit form" command if I don't send the optional "with values" param. So I know I have the basics setup correctly. The only problem seems to be the arbitrary `record`->`NSDictionary` param.

When I execute the AppleScript above in `AppleScript Editor.app`, I get this error on the Cocoa side:

```
+[NSDictionary scriptingRecordWithDescriptor:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff707c6048
```

and this one on the AppleScript side:

```
error "Fluidium got an error: selected tab of browser window 1 doesn’t understand the submit form message." number -1708 from selected tab of browser window 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? For reference the entire application is open source on GitHub:

http://github.com/itod/fluidium

Comment: I suspect I might not be linking to some framework which I need to link to... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right -- NSDictionaries and AppleScript records seem like they would mix, but they don't actually (NSDictionaries use object keys -- say strings) where AppleScript records use four letter character codes (thanks to their AppleEvent/Classic Mac OS heritage).

See [this thread on Apple's AppleScript Implementer's mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-implementors/2005/Sep/msg00045.html)

So, what you actually need to do, in your case, is to unpack the AppleScript record you have and translate it into your NSDictionary. You could write the code all by yourself, but it's complicated and dives deep into the AE manager.

However, this work has actually been done for you in some underlaying code for [appscript/appscript-objc](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) (appscript is an library for Python and Ruby and Objective-C that lets you communicate with AppleScriptable applications without actually having to use AppleScript. appscript-objc could be used where you would use Cocoa Scripting, but has less of the sucky limitations of that technology.)

The code is [available on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/appscript/). I submitted a patch a few weeks ago to the author so you could build JUST the underlaying foundation for appscript-objc, which is all you need in this case: all you need to do is pack and unpack Applescript/AppleEvent records.

For other googlers, there's another way to do this, that's not using appscript: [ToxicAppleEvents](http://bitbucket.org/schwa/toxic-public/src/tip/Frameworks/ToxicAppleEvents). There's a method in there that translates dictionaries into Apple Event Records.

Comment: Cocoa already knew how to transform between AS record and NSDictionary already when 10.0 was released. But only when you use the old style Script Suite and Script Terminology file (standard from 10.0 through 10.3), this will happen automatically. If you use the new XML description (`.sdef`, introduced with 10.2, standard since 10.4), you will have to tell Cocoa how this translation works by defining a custom record type. The rest of your reply contains some truth, a bit of bogus and is missing the most easiest way to actually do it.

Answer (score 7):

Cocoa will seamlessly convert `NSDictionary` objects to AppleScript (AS) records and the other way round for you, you only need to tell it how to do that.

First of all you need to define a `record-type` in your scripting definition (`.sdef`) file, e.g.

```xml
<record-type  name="http response" code="HTRE">
    <property name="success" code="HTSU" type="boolean"
        description="Was the HTTP call successful?"
    />

    <property name="method" code="HTME" type="text"
        description="Request method (GET|POST|...)."
    />

    <property name="code" code="HTRC" type="integer"
        description="HTTP response code (200|404|...)."
    >
        <cocoa key="replyCode"/>
    </property>

    <property name="body" code="HTBO" type="text"
        description="The body of the HTTP response."
    />
</record-type>
```

The `name` is the name this value will have in the AS record. If the name equals the `NSDictionary` key, no `<cocoa>` tag is required (`success`, `method`, `body` in the example above), if not, you can use a `<cocoa>` tag to tell Cocoa the correct key for reading this value (in the example above, `code` is the name in the AS record, but in the `NSDictionary` the key will be `replyCode` instead; I just made this for demonstration purposes here).

It is very important that you tell Cocoa what AS type this field shall have, otherwise Cocoa doesn't know how to transform that value to an AS value. All values are optional by default but if they are present, they must have the expected type. Here's a small table of how the most common Foundation types match to AS types (incomplete):

```
 AS Type     | Foundation Type
-------------+-----------------
 boolean     | NSNumber
 date        | NSDate
 file        | NSURL
 integer     | NSNumber
 number      | NSNumber
 real        | NSNumber
 text        | NSString
```

See [Table 1-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001976-SW11) of Apple's "*Introduction to Cocoa Scripting Guide*"

Of course, a value can itself be another nested record, just define a `record-type` for it, use the `record-type` name in the `property` specification and in the `NSDictionary` the value must then be a matching dictionary.

Well, let's try a full sample. Let's define a simple HTTP get command in our `.sdef` file:

```xml
<command name="http get" code="httpGET_">
    <cocoa class="HTTPFetcher"/>
    <direct-parameter type="text"
        description="URL to fetch."
    />
    <result type="http response"/>
</command>
```

Now we need to implement that command in Obj-C which is dead simple:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// The code below assumes you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).
// It will leak memory if you don't!

// We just subclass NSScriptCommand
@interface HTTPFetcher : NSScriptCommand
@end


@implementation HTTPFetcher

static NSString
    *const SuccessKey   = @"success",
    *const MethodKey    = @"method",
    *const ReplyCodeKey = @"replyCode",
    *const BodyKey      = @"body"
;

// This is the only method we must override
- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    // We expect a string parameter
    id directParameter = [self directParameter];
    if (![directParameter isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return nil;

    // Valid URL?
    NSString * urlString = directParameter;
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if (!url) return @{ SuccessKey : @(false) };

    // We must run synchronously, even if that blocks main thread
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    if (!sem) return nil;

    // Setup the simplest HTTP get request possible.
    NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if (!req) return nil;

    // This is where the final script result is stored.
    __block NSDictionary * result = nil;

    // Setup a data task
    NSURLSession * ses = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * tsk = [ses dataTaskWithRequest:req
        completionHandler:^(
            NSData *_Nullable data,
            NSURLResponse *_Nullable response,
            NSError *_Nullable error
        ) {
            if (error) {
                result = @{ SuccessKey : @(false) };

            } else {
                NSHTTPURLResponse * urlResp = (
                    [response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]] ?
                    (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response : nil
                );

                // Of course that is bad code! Instead of always assuming UTF8
                // encoding, we should look at the HTTP headers and see if
                // there is a charset enconding given. If we downloaded a
                // webpage it may also be found as a meta tag in the header
                // section of the HTML. If that all fails, we should at
                // least try to guess the correct encoding.
                NSString * body = (
                    data ?
                    [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                    ]
                    : nil
                );

                NSMutableDictionary * mresult = [
                    @{ SuccessKey: @(true),
                        MethodKey: req.HTTPMethod
                    } mutableCopy
                ];
                if (urlResp) {
                    mresult[ReplyCodeKey] = @(urlResp.statusCode);
                }
                if (body) {
                    mresult[BodyKey] = body;
                }
                result = mresult;
            }

            // Unblock the main thread
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
        }
    ];
    if (!tsk) return nil;

    // Start the task and wait until it has finished
    [tsk resume];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return result;
}
```

Of course, returning `nil` in case of internal failures is bad error handling. We could return an error instead. Well, there are even special error handling methods for AS we could use here (e.g. setting certain properties we inherited from `NSScriptCommand`), but it's just a sample after all.

Finally we need some AS code to test it:

```
tell application "MyCoolApp"
    set httpResp to http get "http://badserver.invalid"
end tell
```

Result:

```
{success:false}
```

As expected, now one that succeeds:

```
tell application "MyCoolApp"
    set httpResp to http get "http://stackoverflow.com"
end tell
```

Result:

```
{success:true, body:"<!DOCTYPE html>...",  method:"GET", code:200}
```

Also as expected.

But wait, you wanted it the other way round, right? Okay, let's try that as well. We just reuse our type and make another command:

```xml
<command name="print http response" code="httpPRRE">
    <cocoa class="HTTPResponsePrinter"/>
    <direct-parameter type="http response"
        description="HTTP response to print"
    />
</command>
```

And we implement that command as well:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HTTPResponsePrinter : NSScriptCommand
@end


@implementation HTTPResponsePrinter

- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    // We expect a dictionary parameter
    id directParameter = [self directParameter];
    if (![directParameter isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) return nil;

    NSDictionary * dict = directParameter;
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@", dict);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

And we test it:

```
tell application "MyCoolApp"
    set httpResp to http get "http://stackoverflow.com"
    print http response httpResp
end tell
```

And her is what our app logs to console:

```
Dictionary is {
    body = "<!DOCTYPE html>...";
    method = GET;
    replyCode = 200;
    success = 1;
}
```

So, of course, it works both ways.

Well, you may complain now that this is not really *arbitrary*, after all you need to define which keys (may) exist and what type they will have if they exist. You are right. However, usually data is not that arbitrary, I mean, after all code must be able to understand it and therefor it must at least follow certain kind of rules and patterns.

If you really have no idea what data to expect, e.g. like a dump tool that just converts between two well defined data formats without any understand of the data itself, why do you pass it as a record at all? Why don't you just convert that record to an easily parse-able string value (e.g. Property List, JSON, XML, CSV), then pass it Cocoa as a string and finally convert it back to objects? This is a dead simple, yet very powerful approach. Parsing Property List or JSON in Cocoa is done with maybe four lines of code. Okay, it's maybe not the fastest approach but whoever mentions AppleScript and high performance in a single sentence already made a fundamental mistake to begin with; AppleScript certainly may be a lot but "fast" is none of the properties you can expect.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, but there is no need to use semaphore, `NSScriptCommand` has `suspend` and `resume` methods.

Comment: @vadian How will `suspend` and `resume` make my main thread wait till the asynchronous script command has completed? As far as I understand the documentation, it is used to suspend/resume execution of the command but that's not what I'm using the semaphore for.

Comment: Just replace `dispatch_semaphore_create` with `[self suspendExecution];` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);` with `[self resumeExecutionWithResult:result];` and delete `dispatch_semaphore_wait...`. It does exactly the same as the semaphore but in a native way. Maybe you might dispatch `resume` to the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the fields in the dictionary you are wrapping and the types of keys you want to map to / from AppleScript are predictable, it appears the best solution is [to use a record definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37327603/504931) as noted in another answer which also helpfully links to Apple's documentation that I at least personally had completely missed from the scripting guide.

If those above requirements do not for whatever reason fit your needs, an alternative solution is to implement `+scriptingRecordWithDescriptor:` as a category to NSDictionary. I found this solution in the [Fluidium](http://github.com/itod/fluidium) project the question referred to. Here's a paste from [NSDictionary+FUScripting.m](https://github.com/mital/fluidium/blob/master/Fluidium/src/NSDictionary%2BFUScripting.m):

```
@implementation NSDictionary (FUScripting)

+ (id)scriptingRecordWithDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)inDesc {
    //NSLog(@"inDesc: %@", inDesc);

    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSAppleEventDescriptor *withValuesParam = [inDesc descriptorForKeyword:'usrf']; // 'usrf' keyASUserRecordFields
    //NSLog(@"withValuesParam: %@", withValuesParam);

    NSString *name = nil;
    NSString *value = nil;

    // this is 1-indexed!
    NSInteger i = 1;
    NSInteger count = [withValuesParam numberOfItems];
    for ( ; i <= count; i++) {
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [withValuesParam descriptorAtIndex:i];
        //NSLog(@"descriptorAtIndex: %@", desc);

        NSString *s = [desc stringValue];
        if (name) {
            value = s;
            [d setObject:value forKey:name];
            name = nil;
            value = nil;
        } else {
            name = s;
        }
    }

    return [d copy];
}

@end
```

I can confirm that using +scriptingRecordWithDecriptor: with a custom command of the equivalent kind worked for me.

Comment: Lol. That's my (OP) solution to this original problem I had asked right here on Stack Overflow. But you're right :).

Comment: Todd: yep, indeed I simply dug in your question and the Fluidium source some more, and removed a single -autorelease from the return value to ARCify it LOL... Listed here for ease for others to find after I confirmed it 'still' works. I've found quite a few unanswered for Stack Overflow questions related to AppleScript which require far too much detective work :-)

Comment: Wow, so complicated. All that is required is to define a custom `record-type` in your `sdef` file and Cocoa does all the magic for you. See my reply.

Comment: Very nice. If you don't include the type definitions for keys in the record, do they get included in the record at all?

Comment: `type` is a mandatory field for properties, you whole `sdef` is ignored if you fail to specify a type. If the `NSDictionary` or record contains fields that are not defined in your `sdef`, these are simply not transformed (they are silently ignored). If the data is really arbitrary, I won't use dictionaries at all, I'd create a single string in AS and pass that to Cocoa and parse it (e.g. a JSON string can be parsed with 4 lines of code - or if you must support very old MacOS versions, I'd use an XML plist, also 4 lines of code to parse).

Comment: Right. My kind of solution is as far as I can tell then necessary in case where either types are not known before runtime, and when there are possible optional keys, otherwise appears unnecessary. I'll adapt my solution to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

11.9.2016, Mac OS 10.11.6
The problem is: how to convert an AppleScript record into an NSDictionary in the cocoa world ?

The AppleScript record uses AppleScript properties as keys and numbers or strings as values.

The NSDictionary uses the corresponding cocoa keys as keys (in form of NSString objects) and NSNumber or NSString values for four most basic types in the AppleScript record: string, integer, double, and boolean.

The proposed solution for + (id)scriptingRecordWithDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)inDesc did not work in my case.

The basic change in my implementation is that each class in the AppleScript environment defines its own properties and AppleScript codes. The key object to determine is a NSScriptClassDescription which contains the relationship between AppleScript codes and Cocoa keys. 
An additional complication is that the NSAppleEventDescriptor used as parameter in the method represents the incoming AppleScript record (or list of records in my case). This NSAppleEventDescriptor can have different forms.

One entry in the AppleScript record is special: {class:"script class name"}. The codes tests for its presence.

The only replacement you have to do in the code is to introduce the name of your's application AppleScript suite for "Name of your apple script suite" . 
The method is implemented as a Category on NSDictionary

```
#import "NSDictionary+AppleScript.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (AppleScript)

// returns a Dictionary from a apple script record
+ (NSArray <NSDictionary *> * )scriptingRecordWithDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)anEventDescriptor {
    NSScriptSuiteRegistry * theRegistry = [NSScriptSuiteRegistry sharedScriptSuiteRegistry] ;

    DescType theScriptClassDescriptor = [anEventDescriptor descriptorType] ;

    DescType printDescriptorType = NSSwapInt(theScriptClassDescriptor) ;
    NSString * theEventDescriptorType = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&printDescriptorType length:sizeof(DescType) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    //NSLog(@"Event descriptor type: %@", theEventDescriptorType) ; // "list" if a list, "reco" if a simple record , class identifier if a class

    // Forming a list of AppleEventDescriptors
    NSInteger i ;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor * aDescriptor ;
    NSMutableArray <NSAppleEventDescriptor*> * listOfEventDescriptors = [NSMutableArray array] ;
    if ([theEventDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"list"]) {
        NSInteger numberOfEvents = [anEventDescriptor numberOfItems] ;
        for (i = 1 ; i <= numberOfEvents ; i++) {
            aDescriptor = [anEventDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:i] ;
            if (aDescriptor) [listOfEventDescriptors addObject:aDescriptor] ;
        }
    }
    else [listOfEventDescriptors addObject:anEventDescriptor] ;

    // transforming every NSAppleEventDescriptor into an NSDictionary - key: cocoa key - object: NSString - the parameter value as string
    NSMutableArray <NSDictionary *> * theResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:listOfEventDescriptors.count] ;
    for (aDescriptor in listOfEventDescriptors) {
        theScriptClassDescriptor = [aDescriptor descriptorType] ;

        DescType printDescriptorType = NSSwapInt(theScriptClassDescriptor) ;
        NSString * theEventDescriptorType = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&printDescriptorType length:sizeof(DescType) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
        //NSLog(@"Event descriptor type: %@", theEventDescriptorType) ;

        NSMutableDictionary * aRecord = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] ;
        NSInteger numberOfAppleEventItems = [aDescriptor numberOfItems] ;
        //NSLog(@"Number of items: %li", numberOfAppleEventItems) ;

        NSScriptClassDescription * (^determineClassDescription)() = ^NSScriptClassDescription *() {
            NSScriptClassDescription * theResult ;

            NSDictionary * theClassDescriptions = [theRegistry classDescriptionsInSuite:@"Arcadiate Suite"] ;
            NSArray * allClassDescriptions = theClassDescriptions.allValues ;
            NSInteger numOfClasses = allClassDescriptions.count ;
            if (numOfClasses == 0) return theResult ;

            NSMutableData * thePropertiesCounter = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(numOfClasses * sizeof(NSInteger))] ;
            NSInteger *propertiesCounter = [thePropertiesCounter mutableBytes] ;
            AEKeyword aKeyWord  ;
            NSInteger classCounter = 0 ;
            NSScriptClassDescription * aClassDescription ;
            NSInteger i ;
            NSString * aCocoaKey ;
            for (aClassDescription in allClassDescriptions) {
                for (i = 1 ; i <= numberOfAppleEventItems ; i++) {
                    aKeyWord = [aDescriptor keywordForDescriptorAtIndex:i] ;
                    aCocoaKey = [aClassDescription keyWithAppleEventCode:aKeyWord] ;
                    if (aCocoaKey.length > 0) propertiesCounter[classCounter] ++ ;
                }
                classCounter ++ ;
            }
            NSInteger maxClassIndex = NSNotFound ;
            for (i = 0 ; i < numOfClasses ; i++) {
                if (propertiesCounter[i] > 0) {
                    if (maxClassIndex != NSNotFound) {
                        if (propertiesCounter[i] > propertiesCounter[maxClassIndex]) maxClassIndex = i ;
                    }
                    else maxClassIndex = i ;
                }
            }
            //NSLog(@"Max class index: %li", maxClassIndex) ;
            //if (maxClassIndex != NSNotFound) NSLog(@"Number of matching properties: %li", propertiesCounter[maxClassIndex]) ;
            if (maxClassIndex != NSNotFound) theResult = allClassDescriptions[maxClassIndex] ;
            return theResult ;
        } ;

        NSScriptClassDescription * theRelevantScriptClass ;
        if ([theEventDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"reco"]) theRelevantScriptClass = determineClassDescription() ;
        else theRelevantScriptClass = [theRegistry classDescriptionWithAppleEventCode:theScriptClassDescriptor] ;
        if (theRelevantScriptClass) {
        //NSLog(@"Targeted Script Class: %@", theRelevantScriptClass) ;

            NSString * aCocoaKey, *stringValue ;
            NSInteger integerValue ;
            BOOL booleanValue ;
            id aValue ;
            stringValue = [theRelevantScriptClass implementationClassName] ;
            if (stringValue.length > 0) aRecord[@"className"] = aValue ;
            AEKeyword aKeyWord ;
            NSAppleEventDescriptor * parameterDescriptor ;
            NSString * printableParameterDescriptorType ;
            DescType parameterDescriptorType ;
            for (i = 1 ; i <= numberOfAppleEventItems ; i++) {
                aValue = nil ;
                aKeyWord = [aDescriptor keywordForDescriptorAtIndex:i] ;
                aCocoaKey = [theRelevantScriptClass keyWithAppleEventCode:aKeyWord] ;
                parameterDescriptor = [aDescriptor paramDescriptorForKeyword:aKeyWord] ;
                parameterDescriptorType = [parameterDescriptor descriptorType] ;
                printDescriptorType = NSSwapInt(parameterDescriptorType) ;
                printableParameterDescriptorType = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&printDescriptorType length:sizeof(DescType) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
                //NSLog(@"Parameter type: %@", printableParameterDescriptorType) ;

                if ([printableParameterDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"doub"]) {
                    stringValue = [parameterDescriptor stringValue] ;
                    if (stringValue.length > 0) {
                        aValue = @([stringValue doubleValue]) ;
                    }
                }
                else if ([printableParameterDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"long"]) {
                    integerValue = [parameterDescriptor int32Value] ;
                    aValue = @(integerValue) ;
                }
                else if ([printableParameterDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"utxt"]) {
                    stringValue = [parameterDescriptor stringValue] ;
                    if (stringValue.length > 0) {
                        aValue = stringValue ;
                    }
                }
                else if ( ([printableParameterDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"true"]) || ([printableParameterDescriptorType isEqualToString:@"fals"]) ) {
                    booleanValue = [parameterDescriptor booleanValue] ;
                    aValue = @(booleanValue) ;
                }
                else {
                    stringValue = [parameterDescriptor stringValue] ;
                    if (stringValue.length > 0) {
                        aValue = stringValue ;
                    }
                }
                if ((aCocoaKey.length != 0) && (aValue)) aRecord[aCocoaKey] = aValue ;
            }
        }
        [theResult addObject:aRecord] ;
    }
    return theResult ;
}
@end
```

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer, and several other very detailed answers. Your's does provide any additional information.

Comment: Yes, my solution adds new information and yes, one other answer was sufficient for simple cases. The easiest solution is to define a new type in AppleScript - something like a genuine record type that defines all keys which will ever be used in a record in AppleScript. Every record to be used should than be defined as being from this genuine record type. - However for larger Apple Suits this tends to go out of hands. Depending on the class the same key might have different implementations in Cocoa - hence a more genuine - class typed - solution is required. This is what my code offers.