# Returning a record-type to applescript (from objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, applescript, cocoa-scripting

I am trying to return a record to applescript. The current solution is to return an NSDictionary and define the a record-type (Lyx return value) in the sdef file, but this does not work - should I construct a specific AppleScript object?

Here is the sdef file

```
<!-- our special scripting suite for this example -->
<suite name="Lyx" code="LYX " description="LyX scripting facilities.">

    <record-type name="LyX return value" code="LyxR">
        <property name="code" code="code" type="integer"
            description="Error code (0 in case of success).">
            <cocoa key="code"/>
        </property>            
        <property name="message" code="mess" type="text"
            description="The returned message.">
            <cocoa key="message"/>
        </property>
    </record-type>

    <command name="run" code="SLyxComm" description="run a simple command with one parameter">
        <cocoa class="LyxCommand"/>

        <direct-parameter description="The command to be executed.">
            <type type="text" list="no"/>
        </direct-parameter>

        <parameter name="with argument" code="args" type="text">
            <cocoa key="arg"/>
        </parameter>

        <result type="LyX return value" description="Contains a code (0 for success) and the message returned by LyX"/>
    </command>

</suite>
```

and here is the objective-C code

```
@interface LyxCommand : NSScriptCommand {
}
- (id)performDefaultImplementation;
@end

@implementation LyxCommand
- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    // Get the command and argument
    NSDictionary * theArguments = [self evaluatedArguments];

  NSString * directParameter = [self directParameter];
  NSString *arg = [theArguments objectForKey: @"arg"];


  // Execute the command
  LyXFunctionResult result = applescript_execute_command([directParameter UTF8String], [arg UTF8String]);

  // Construct the result record
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithCString:result.message encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  free(result.message); 

  NSDictionary *objcResult = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:result.code], @"code", message, @"message", nil];
  return objcResult;
}

@end
```

When I try this simple aplescript

```
tell application "LyX-2.1-qt4"
set x to (run "server-get-filename" with argument "")
end tell
message of x
```

the error message is: `error "Can’t get message of {message:\"\", code:0}." number -1728 from message of {«class mess»:"", «class code»:0}`.

Comment: with `code of x` or `get (message of x)`, same error: `error "Can’t get code of {message:\"\", code:0}." number -1728 from code of {«class mess»:"", «class code»:0}`.

Comment: BTW, you should not use all-lowercase codes for your custom names because they are reserved by Apple and might clash with yours, meaning different things. Such as where you use code="mess" and code="code".

Comment: Maybe one of my answers to a similar question might be helpful for oyu. Give it a try (and don't forget to upvote if you like it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/37327603/15809

Answer (score 0):

Your sdef and implementation are fine, however the terminology you define in your sdef is NOT available outside of the AppleScript tell block. Your script should be:

```
tell application "LyX-2.1-qt4"
    set x to (run "server-get-filename" with argument "")
    message of x
end tell
```

or, if you really need the message outside of the tell block for some reason:

```
set msg to missing value
tell application "LyX-2.1-qt4"
    set x to (run "server-get-filename" with argument "")
    set msg to message of x
end tell
log msg
```